# POST using JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Estoy intentado una petición post mediante una URL, ya la probe en postman con el siguiente codigo JSON y funciono:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ahora lo que estoy intentando hacer es que esa petición como en postman se haga en springTool, la estoy haciendo así:

```
@PostMapping("/saveEmailTemplateREST")
public String saveEmailTemplateREST(@Validated EmailTemplateREST emailTemplateREST, Model model) throws IOException, JSONException {
    listEmailsTemplatesREST.add(emailTemplateREST);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("asunto", "NotifyIt: Email Test from Prod-4 20210528-18:09");   
    json.put("contenidoRich", "<html><body>This a simple email test with attachment!</body></html>");  
    json.put("emailFrom", "ejemplo.com");  
    json.put("destinoMdestinoMailail", "ejemplo.com"); 
    json.put("mailcc", ""); 
    json.put("nombrePlantilla", "Test template from SpringTool"); 
    json.put("digitalsign", "false"); 
    json.put("signFile", "null"); 
    json.put("adjuntoPlantillado", "null"); 
    json.put("adjuntos", "null");

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    
    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://sandbox.notify-it.com/notify/services/createEmailTemplate?u=admin.operaciones@notify-it.com&t=01fd9a1c-7156-4108-be80-fd318f248f62");
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        request.setEntity(params);
        httpClient.execute(request);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        httpClient.close();
    }
    
    return "redirect:/emailTemplates";
}
```

El problema es que no funciona, no me da error ni nada cuando ejecuto el metodo, no se por que no funcionara.

Comment: Dices " no me da error ni nada " pero no estas imprimiendo algún error dentro de  catch (Exception ex) {, te sugiero imprimir para saber que mensaje obtienes

Comment: si no da error como sabes que "no funciona"?

Comment: se que no funciona, por que no me inserta los datos

Answer (score 0):

En su momento utilice este ejemplo para implementar uno.

```
@Test
public void whenPostJsonUsingHttpClient_thenCorrect() 
  throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com");

    String json = "{"id":1,"name":"John"}";
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), equalTo(200));
    client.close();
}
```

Como dice el comentario, puedes poner el log para saber más al respecto.